# RavenDB Query Language

Tags: ravendb

I'm trying to find duplicates in some raven docs, but I am know nothing about the RQL. My document is a **Product** document that has many **Items**. Items contain a field, *PartNumber*, which "should" be unique across all Products.

I need a query that will show my products, that have items, that are not unique.

Here's a mock of my **Product** document. (Take with a grain of salt - it's freehand)

```
{
    "ProductNumber": "O11223-AABBDD"
    "Items" : [
        {
            "PartNumber": "AAAAAA-001"
        },
        {
            "PartNumber": "AAAAAA-002"
        },
    ]
}
```

Using RQL, how can I query my Products documents to report to me Products that has Items[].PartNumber that are not unique across all Products?

Answer (score 0):

RavenDB has a nice feature called: **Compare Exchange** that can be used to maintain uniqueness across your documents.

See in **live-studio**: http://live-test.ravendb.net/studio/index.html
(under the Documents menu item in any database)

See in **Docs**: https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/Csharp/client-api/operations/compare-exchange/overview

See in **Blog**: https://ayende.com/blog/182948-C/distributed-compare-exchange-operations-with-ravendb

---

Also,
You can define a Map-Index on 'Items' and then query that index for a value, and if the query result will contain more than one documents than you know it is not unique.

**Learn about indexes here:**
https://ravendb.net/docs/article-page/4.2/csharp/studio/database/indexes/indexes-overview

**See live demo examples here:**

https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/static-indexes-overview

https://demo.ravendb.net/demos/csharp/static-indexes/map-index

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to post an answer. But I need to query the repository.